# How to remove submodule changes in a local commit?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a local git commit that hasn't been pushed to remote yet. I accidentally added changes from a submodule into the local commit. If it weren't part of the commit, I know I can just do a `git reset`, but because it's already part of the commit, I'm not sure what to do.

I went into the submodule and did a `git reset --hard origin` and then amended my commit, but this didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Short version of what you need to do, in order:

1. enter the submodule (e.g., `cd path-to-submodule`;
2. select the desired commit (e.g., `git checkout hash`, `git switch --detach hash`, or even `git reset --hard hash`);
3. return to the superproject (e.g., `cd -` or `cd ../../..` depending on the path to the submodule);
4. `git add path-to-submodule`;
5. `git commit --amend`.

You've already done steps 1 and 2, assuming `origin` resolves to the appropriate hash ID.  (Note that `origin`, as a name for a hash ID, resolves to `origin/HEAD` which in turn resolves to `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`: see step 6 of the six-step process outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  You can run `git rev-parse origin/HEAD` within the submodule repository so as to see the raw hash ID obtained here.)

#### Long-ish explanation with details

A Git commit is made up of two parts, which I normally describe this way:

- Each commit holds a *full snapshot* of all of the files Git knows about.
- Each commit also holds some *metadata*, or information about the commit.

When dealing with submodules, the only real change here is in the first point.  Besides the *files*, the superproject commits also contain *gitlinks*, one for each submodule.  A gitlink is a lot like a symbolic link, only different:

- A *symbolic link*, which is supported on most Unix-like file systems and some Windows systems, is in essence a file that contains the name of another file.  The operating system is set up so that when you ask to open and read the file (e.g., `path/to/file.ext`), the OS notices that this is a symlink rather than a regular file, so it opens and reads `path/to/file.ext` itself, finds that `path/to/file.ext` contains, say, the text string `../../other.name`, and puts these together to read `path/to/../../other.name` and thus opens and reads `other.name` in the current directory (the two `..`s driving back up over `to` and `path` respectively).
- A *gitlink* is interpreted by Git itself: it's a raw hash ID for some commit in *some other Git repository*.

Each file entry in a commit has a path name such as `path/name`, and a gitlink is no exception: it has a name, `path/name` or whatever.  Then it has a raw hash ID.  Git reads the name and looks in a separate table of submodules (filled in, initially, from the `.gitmodules` file at the top of the commit's snapshot).  The *table* says that submodule `path/name` is to be cloned from some URL, so `git submodule update --init` will run `git clone` on that URL and clone the repository.  It then proceeds to do the regular `git submodule update` as below.

Later (or right now), any `git submodule update` will:

- enter the submodule (`cd path/name` in this case);
- use the raw hash ID from the gitlink to run `git checkout hash` or `git switch --detach hash`.

(The checkout vs switch distinction vanishes in Git versions predating Git 2.23, where `git switch` was added, but by using `--detach` this is a distinction without a difference: both do the same thing.  There's also a `git fetch` step in the submodule.  I am eliding it on purpose as it's optional and a little tricky.  If your submodule clone is a full clone, and there are no new submodule commits, the `git fetch` step doesn't do anything, so we can ignore it here.  I'm also eliding certain options you can manually pass to `git submodule update` as they make things more confusing, without really enlightening anyone at this point.)

Using `--recursive` (as in `git clone --recursive`, `git checkout --recursive`, or `git switch --recursive`) tells Git to employ all the submodule magic via `git submodule update --init` automatically, so that you don't have to think about it, but doesn't change the fundamental process: Git first checks out the commit in the superproject so as to obtain the gitlink path and raw hash ID, and then clones and/or enters the submodule as needed and checks out the commit whose hash ID is given by the gitlink.  **In all of these cases you wind up with the submodule checked out as a "detached HEAD".**  That's the normal way submodules work and it's why, in step 2 in the short version above, I recommend `git checkout` or `git switch --detach` rather than `git reset --hard` (though all will work).

#### What the long-ish explanation means

The *superproject* repository *does not contain any submodule files*.  Instead, it contains:

- a `.gitmodules` file, which gives the *instructions Git needs to run `git clone`*; and
- for each submodule, a *gitlink* giving a path and a raw hash ID.

Hence, as you make new commits in the superproject, you're putting two things into each of these commits to go with your superproject files:

1. You're committing another copy of `.gitmodules`.  As this is probably exactly the same as every previous copy, the new commit's copy is literally shared with all the previous commits' copies, so it takes no space.  It's a "virtual" copy rather than a "physical" copy.  But it's still a "copy", as far as thinking about it goes.
2. You're committing a *gitlink*.  This gitlink has a path name—that's the submodule's path name—and a raw hash ID.  When you run `git add` in step 4 in the short version, what you're doing is setting up your *next commit*—the one you make in step 5—to hold the desired hash ID.  To make sure you get the *right* hash ID, you execute step 2 in the short version.

Running `git add path/name`, assuming the path to the submodule is `path/name`, is really an instruction to the superproject Git:

- enter the submodule;
- run `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the raw hash ID;
- leave the submodule;
- update the gitlink in the index / staging-area.

The `git commit` then makes the new commit from the superproject's index / staging-area as usual, but because you ran `git add`, the new commit has a new gitlink hash ID.

Using `git commit --amend` as we do in the short version means that we kick the *previous* commit off the end of the current (superproject) branch and add instead a different new commit.  The different new commit has the correct gitlink; the previous tip commit was mostly correct but had the wrong gitlink.

Once you can think about a gitlink as a "file" that you store in every commit, you actually understand submodules.

Comment: I just tried the list of steps, but it seems nothing happened. One question I have is after you do step 3 and then a `git status`, should I see the third party submodule listed? In my case, I didn't see anything listed

Comment: No and yes: it depends in part on your settings for `status.submoduleSummary` and `submodule.<name>.ignore`. I generally run `git submodule status` separately for submodules myself (well, I generally *avoid* submodules when I can: there are many reasons people call them "sob"-modules). Note that it's possible that your existing commit already has the gitlink hash ID you want: to find out what's in it, us e`git ls-tree` or `git rev-parse` (or `git submodule` with summary and/or status sub-commands).

Comment: As an example, the Git repository for Git includes a submodule, `sha1collisiondetection`, that's normally not even init-ed. `git status` says nothing about it, and `git submodule summary` says nothing, but `git submodule status` shows `-855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2 sha1collisiondetection` for this un-init-ed submodule. `git rev-parse HEAD:sha1collisiondetection` shows the gitlink in the HEAD commit and `git rev-parse :sha1collisiondetection` shows the gitlink in Git's index.